# Symfony don't generate new bundle

Tags: symfony, command-line, bundle

I try to generate bundle in Symfony 2, using command line tool.
After running bundle:generate command, there is no generated bundle in /src folder.

Watch this short video to see a problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zKgaqWz8rs

There is no any errors in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you're in the wrong directory.
you look at `Computer/F:/symfony/src` and the composer told you it generated a bundle in `F:/xampp/htdocs/symfony/src`.
so take a look in `F:/xampp/htdocs/symfony/src`, it might be there.

Comment: God, I'am so stupid :P You are absolutely right, i think i need some rest. And why i have F:/symfony direcotry anyway...